# how trigger the 'exit' application event in nativescript with angular 2 in onclick of logout button view?

Tags: typescript, angular2-nativescript

I want to exit the entire application in on Tap() of logout button in nativescript app. I referred the use of application events in below link.
https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/application-lifecycle

I want more idea on this?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 5):

I don't advocate exiting your app programmatically, but it can be done with a bit of code.

On iOS you'd do:

```
exit(0)
```

And on Android:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

There's a plugin making it even easier for you: https://github.com/dvabuzyarov/nativescript-exit

Comment: For Android would be more natural to use `application.android.foregroundActivity.finish();` method.

Answer (score 2):

- Install "nativescript-exit" `npm i nativescript-exit`
- Import exit function `import { exit } from "nativescript-exit";`
- call exit function `exit();`

```js
import { exit } from "nativescript-exit"; 
// to instal 'nativescript-exit' run in root folder(where node_modules are): 
// npm i nativescript-exit

public logOut(): void {
  exit(); // will close application
}
```

```html
    <Button text="Log out" (tap)="logOut()"></Button>
```